# Does anybody know of a USB Postage Scale that's Linux compatible?

Tags: linux, usb, scale

I'm looking for a postage scale that already has linux support (drivers, etc) for a shipping system that I'm working on. I'm planning to use Ubuntu 9.04, but I am willing to switch distro's for compatibility.

Does anybody know of any scales that currently work? Is there an open source project that's working on scale drivers or similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use the 5lb stamps.com scale.  You can pick it up for $10 if you sign up for an account with them and then cancel it.

To read from it in linux, get this script: http://gist.github.com/503896

Edit the script file to set the proper hidraw device path.  You can find the path by running `dmesg` after you've plugged the scale in.  You will see something like "/dev/hidraw2".

After setting the hidraw path in the script, add execute permission and then run it as root:

chmod +x usbscale.pl

sudo ./usbscale.pl

Place an object on the scale and it will print the weight.

Comment: Thanks for the info! We're already stamps.com customers (it's their API we're using for our app). BUT the free scale we got (a long time ago) doesn't have USB at all. It must be a newer scale that's USB compatible. I could call and ask them if they'll give us the newer scale. 5 LBS will do most of what we ship. We do need to go up to 30 LBS sometimes though. BUT thanks for the script link, its a good starting place for me to modify.

Comment: This Stamps.com scale looks like it goes to 25LBS. Is it like the one you have that works with the script? http://customer.stamps.com/Store/catalog/sku.jsp?productId=prod22441145&id=SC00002510

Comment: I'm not sure...it said 5lbs on the website when I got it.  But, I've definitely used it to weigh things that are more than 5lbs and it seemed accurate.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

I've created a newer version of my earlier script that mattismyname linked. It's written in C, and you can find it at https://github.com/erjiang/usbscale

To use it, just download the source code and run (inside its directory):

```
sudo aptitude install libusb-1.0-0-dev
make
./usbscale
```

You might need to copy the `50-usb-scales.rules` to your `/etc/udev/rules.d` (or run as `root`, haha) if you run into a permissions error.

Answer (score 0):

Exponent value is passed as signed integer, and weight is passed in little endian byte order. Other answers [do not properly account](https://github.com/erjiang/usbscale/commit/f4c33e687da7ae977d555e82319c42ca33da2615) for these factors. [See a more comprehensive example here.](https://github.com/sanmai/usb-scale-reader/blob/master/example/read_stupid.php)

```
<?php
$binary = fread(fopen('/dev/hidraw3', 'r'), 7);
$data = (object) unpack('Creport/Cstatus/Cunit/cexponent/vweight', $binary);

if ($data->report == 0x03 && $data->status == 0x04) {
    $data->weight = $data->weight * pow(10, $data->exponent);
    if ($data->unit == 0x0B) {
        // convert ounces to grams
        $data->weight *= 28.349523125;
        // and unit to grams
        $data->unit = 0x02;
    }

    if ($data->unit == 0x02) {
        echo "{$data->weight} g\n";
    } else {
        echo "{$data->weight} in other unit\n";
    }
}
```